# Get all records 60 degree North in SQL with query on Latitude-Longitude Column?

Tags: sql-server, latitude-longitude

I have table with latitude & longitude columns in SQL.
how can I select all records with lat-long 60 degree North or greater (Arctic Region)

Answer (score 4):

how about:

```
select * from table where latitude > 60.0;
```

Comment: its not giving correct result.

Comment: in what way is it not correct?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that if you have a large dataset then defining your data using lat / long, instead of using a real GIS geometry like PostGIS geography or geometry, prevents you from building spatial indexes on your data.  You could get by with building a B+-tree index on your latitude field for the query iant provided, but the moment you need to start doing queries involving both longitude and latitude your indexes will perform sub-par (even if you have two separate indexes on both lat and lon).